Visual Studio Code Syntax Highlighting for Excel Formulae/Functions
For convenience, I often temporarily copy large Excel formulae/functions into Visual Studio Code for editing, then copy them back. The software tends to identify those as 'ini' files and highlight them accordingly, which means some of its highlights are questionable. What would be the best highlighting option for editing Excel formulae/functions, whether out of the stock highlighting options, or one that I could easily install as an extension?

To clarify, you're taking the formulas you would type into cells and putting it into the VBA window to edit, due to length. And you're looking for an add-in that will highlight excel-formula syntax errors in the VBA window? Is this separate from having the "Auto Syntax Check" turned on in the options?

Consider using the Excel Labs add-in for Excel. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/excel-labs/

@MarkS. Formulae from cells, yes. Which I copy to VSC (not VBA) for ease of editing, the back into cells again.
